# Rearrange the string

Tags: java, string

For Example-

- input1 `String ="2a[2b[c]]"` then output should be "`abcbcabcbc`"
- input2 `String ="2a[b[c]]"`  then output should be "`abcabc`"

```
import java.util.*;
class a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "2a[2b[c]]]";
        // o/p = abcbcabcbc  
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
            s1.push(s.charAt(i));
        }
        String str="";
        String sss="";
        for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++) {
            char a = (char)s1.pop();
            // if(a == '')
            if((int)a >=49 && (int)a<=58){
                for(int i=0;i<(int)a-48;i++){
                    sss+=str;
                    System.out.println(sss);
                }
            }
            else if((int)a >=97 && (int)a <= 122){
                  str = a + str;
                  System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sss);
    }
}
```

but my output is showing like "bcbcabcabc".

Comment: Please explain what is the logic to get from `"2a[2b[c]]"` to `"abcbcabcbc"`.

Comment: This is not an explanation, just another example. Currently your question is not clear enough to help you.

Comment: 2a[2b[c]] it should print 2 times of abc and 2 times of bc like abcbc , abcbc and o/p be abcbcabcbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do `sss+=str;`,please add `sss=str;`.
you forget to update your `sss`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "2a[2b[c]]]";         
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
            s1.push(s.charAt(i));
        }
        String str="";
        String sss="";
        for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++) {
            char a = (char)s1.pop();
            System.out.println("a:"+a);
            // if(a == '')
            if((int)a >=49 && (int)a<=58){
                for(int i=0;i<(int)a-48;i++){
                    sss=str;
                    sss+=str;
                    System.out.println("sss:"+sss);
                }
                str=sss;
            }
            //character
            else if((int)a >=97 && (int)a <= 122){
                str = a + str;
                System.out.println("str:"+str);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sss);
    }
```